# Translating webpage in WordPress with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, poedit

I am looking to translate my wordpress page based on adding a parameter ?lang=de_DE.

Below is my index.php file :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html<?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> <?php echo __('This is our website','basictheme');?> </h1>
   <?php wp_footer(); ?>


</body>
</html>
```

functions.php file

```
<?php

function basictheme_functions() {

    load_theme_textdomain('basictheme',get_template_directory_uri().'/lang');

    add_theme_support('title-tag');

     register_nav_menus(array(
    'main-menu' => __('Main Menu','basictheme'),
    'footer-menu' => __('Footer Menu','basictheme'),
    ));
}
add_action('after_setup_theme','basictheme_functions');



?>
```

How can I translate the page when I add the parameter to the URL.

(e.g `http://localhost/about/?lang=de_DE`)

Comment: Do you want automatic translation of the content of the pages?

Comment: Yes , that's what I would like to achieve. Would you recommend another solution (e.g template page for each language - http://localhost/fr/about/)

Comment: I'd recommend not to do it. Automatic translations are horrible. Always. There are a lot of WordPress plugins that allow multi-language sites, concentrate on your core languages, translate your content and store it per language.